# What are the downsides of randomly generating "id" attribute values?

Tags: html

Sometimes it's necessary give `id` attribute to form fields or other HTML elements to be able to refer to them from elsewhere on the page. For example:

```html
<label for="your-name">Your name:</label>
...
<input type="text" id="your-name">
```

`id` attributes should be unique per page, which can be difficult to ensure if the page is composed of separately developed components. The easiest solution to ensuring unique IDs would be to randomly generate them whenever needed.

Besides the fact that you can't use randomly generated IDs to refer to elements in automated tests, what are the downsides of randomly generating IDs? Are there commonly used frameworks or software doing this without issues already?

(For example, randomly generating `name` attributes for form fields wouldn't be advisable because that would mess up form autofill tools, but are there similar caveats that apply to randomly generated `id`s?)

Comment: Use a relative path id. If is a component inside another component and so on, those components should be unique identified also, and you can create `main-content-form3-name` id. Also, if you have the reference of the HTML element, you don't need ids.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález _“Also, if you have the reference of the HTML element, you don't need ids”_ - very true when element access via JavaScript is concerned, but the specific example given here _needs_ the ID, because that’s what creates the connection between the label and the input. (And sticking the input field _inside_ the label, so that the `for` attribute can be left out, isn’t always possible.)

Comment: May i know why "we can't use randomly generated IDs to refer to elements in automated tests,". I am a new guy  in html ,anybody can explain ?

Comment: @CBroe oh yeah, you are right. Didn't noticed that.

Comment: @ArunK simply that if you create the elements dynamically, you don't need to select them in the DOM again to work with them (I saw that a lot of times. Usual for newbies). You will notice what I'm talking about in the future when you get some experience.